# Is comparison of const_iterator with iterator well-defined?

Tags: c++, iterator, comparison-operators, const-iterator

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,5};
    for(auto it=vec.cbegin();it!=vec.cend();++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it;
        // A typo: end instead of cend
        if(next(it)!=vec.end()) std::cout << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Here I've introduced a typo: in the comparison I called `vec.end()` instead of `vec.cend()`. This appears to work as intended with gcc 5.2. But is it actually well-defined according to the Standard? Can `iterator` and `const_iterator` be safely compared?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Surprisingly, C++98 and C++11 didn't say that you can compare a `iterator` with a `const_iterator`. This leads to [LWG issue 179](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#179) and [LWG issue 2263](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2263). Now in C++14, this is explicitly permitted by § 23.2.1[container.requirements.general]p7

> In the expressions
>
> ```
> i == j
> i != j
> i < j
> i <= j
> i >= j
> i > j
> i - j
> ```
>
> where `i` and `j` denote objects of a container's `iterator` type, either or
>   both may be replaced by an object of the container's `const_iterator`
>   type referring to the same element with no change in semantics.

Comment: That only means that const and non const iterators that comes from a same object matching the `Container` concept can be safely compared. But you cannot make that assumption for other iterators.

Answer (score 11):

Table 96 in the C++11 Standard, in section 23.2.1, defines the *operational semantics* of `a.cend()` for any container type `X` (including `std::vector`) as follows:

```
const_cast<X const &>(a).end()
```

So the answer is yes because by this definition `cend()` refers to the same element/position in the container as `end()`, and `X::iterator` must be convertible to `X::const_iterator` (a requirement also specified in the same table<sup>(*)</sup>).

(The answer is also yes for `begin()` vs. `cbegin()` for the same reasons, as defined in the same table.)

---

<sup>(*)</sup> It has been pointed out in comments to other answers that convertibility does not necessarily imply that the comparison operation `i1==i2` will always work, e.g. if `operator==()` is a member function of the iterator type, the implicit conversion will only be accepted for the righthand-side argument, not the lefthand-side one. 24.2.5/6 states (about forward-iterators `a` and `b`):

> If `a` and `b` are both dereferenceable, then `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object

Even though the iterators `end()` and `cend()` are not dereferenceable, the statement above implies that `operator==()` must be defined in such a way that the comparison is possible even if `a` is a const-iterator and `b` is not, and vice versa, because 24.2.5 is about forward-iterators in general, including both const- and non-const-versions -- this is clear e.g. from 24.2.5/1. This is why I am convinced that the wording from Table 96, which refers to convertibility, also implies comparability. But as described in cpplearner@'s later answer, this has been made explicitly clear only in C++14.

Answer (score 10):

See §23.2.1, Table 96:

> ```
> X::iterator
> ```

[...]

> any iterator category that meets the forward iterator requirements.
>
> **convertible to `X::const_iterator`**

So, yes, it is well-defined.

Comment: _Convertible_ doesn't imply _comparable_.

Comment: For instance, convertible does not rule out comparison operators implemented as member functions, meaning `i  < ci` resolves to `i.operator <(ci)`, where no conversion of `i` gets considered. There may be additional guarantees in the standard, but if so, they should be in the answer.

Comment: @hvd: fortunately, in the questioner's code, the const_iterator is on the LHS of the comparison, and the plain iterator is on the right. So it's converted. Or I guess we could say it's unfortunate, since it means the compiler doesn't catch the unintended use of `end()`.

Comment: @SteveJessop It was just an example. Another is operators that do not take `const_iterator` at all, but simply something that `const_iterator` is implicitly convertible to, requiring two user-defined conversions. A third is a template comparison operator where the type argument cannot be deduced because of a `const_iterator`/`iterator` mismatch. (Luckily there is an answer now that shows the additional requirements in the standard.)